# Splitting results of query into several results

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I currently have the following query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "query": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "ods"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "pds"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "total_per_day": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "createdAt",
                "interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "cumulative": {
                    "cumulative_sum": {
                        "buckets_path": "_count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the nice result:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12425,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "total_per_day": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "1450828800",
          "key": 1450828800000,
          "doc_count": 1379,
          "cumulative": {
            "value": 1379
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "1450915200",
          "key": 1450915200000,
          "doc_count": 11046,
          "cumulative": {
            "value": 12425
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, this gives me a "total" result (which I intended in the first place) of all documents matching the type `ods` or `pds`. While visualizing this, I really do not have a clear overview of what it is constructed of (how many `pds` documents and how many `ods` documents).

My modified query is as following:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "query": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "ods"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "pds"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "total_per_day": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "createdAt",
                "interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "types": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "_type"
                    }
                },
                "cumulative": {
                    "cumulative_sum": {
                        "buckets_path": "_count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Producing the following result

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12963,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "total_per_day": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "1450828800",
          "key": 1450828800000,
          "doc_count": 1379,
          "types": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "pds",
                "doc_count": 834
              },
              {
                "key": "ods",
                "doc_count": 545
              }
            ]
          },
          "cumulative": {
            "value": 1379
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "1450915200",
          "key": 1450915200000,
          "doc_count": 11584,
          "types": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "pds",
                "doc_count": 5840
              },
              {
                "key": "ods",
                "doc_count": 5744
              }
            ]
          },
          "cumulative": {
            "value": 12963
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This already gives me a better insight in my data, however, I'd also like to have a cumulative count per `ods` or `pds` types bucket. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, You are looking for [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html), you could create separate buckets for `ods` and `pds` like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "type_buckets": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "ods_type": {
            "term": {
              "_type": "ods"
            }
          },
          "pds_type": {
            "term": {
              "_type": "pds"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "users_per_day": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "createdAt",
            "interval": "day"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "cumulative": {
              "cumulative_sum": {
                "buckets_path": "_count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1** : Another way to do the same thing is with `filter` and `sub-aggregation` like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ods_type": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "_type": "ods"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "users_per_day": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "created_at",
            "interval": "month"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "cumulative": {
              "cumulative_sum": {
                "buckets_path": "_count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "pds_type": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "_type": "pds"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "users_per_day": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "created_at",
            "interval": "month"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "cumulative": {
              "cumulative_sum": {
                "buckets_path": "_count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: It almost exactly creates what I want, however, now I'm having trouble to loop over the data. To print a cumulative stacked bar chart now, I need to run a complex loop. Right now we have a path of `aggregations.type_buckets.buckets.ods_type.users_per_day.buckets[0].cumulative.value` just to get to the data I need. I'd like to see it as `aggregations.users_per_day.buckets[0].type_buckets.ods_type.cumulative.value`

Comment: I have edited my anwere, please have a look. I am not sure why looping is **complex** in first case. The way you suggested `aggregations.users_per_day.buckets[0].type_buckets.ods_type.cumulative.value` is not possible because `cumulative_sum` needs to have `date_histogram` as parent, with `sub-aggregation` you can use `aggregations.ods_type.users_per_day.buckets[0].cumulative.value`, IMO `filters` approach is more cleaner.